Should line and load wires be connected in my light switch?
I am replacing a light switch in my kitchen that has failed. When I removed the switch, I found that the switch was intended for “permanently installed incandescent fixtures only”. This switch controls two lights - a permanently installed incandescent fixture and a normal recessed light. It may be control something else that I’m not aware of.
The switch has two wires coming out from the back. One wire is pigtailed to one black wire in the wall with a wire nut. The other wire is pigtailed to three black wires in the wall with a wire nut. No neutral wire is connected to the switch.
I removed the switch, turned on the power, and hovered a non-contact voltage tester near the wires coming out of the wall. Only one wire in the group of three had voltage. The single wire did not have voltage. I have attached a labeled photo. The three loose wires were pigtailed together.
I’d like to replace this switch. However, I’m a little confused by the wiring. Is it unusual for only one wire in a group of three to contain voltage? I’d assume that the three wires were line wires and the single wire was the load wire, but this isn’t what the voltage tester is showing.
Should I wire the new switch the same way the old one was? I believe that load and line wires shouldn’t be attached to a single terminal on a light switch, which is why I ask. Should I do something else (e.g. group together the wires without voltage and leave the one with voltage alone)? Or hire an electrician?
Thank you!



What are you calling a fixture here?  You say you removed the fixture and found these black wires, but your pic shows what appears to be a switch—is that what you mean?  Do you need to edit your post?

Fixed confusing use of terminology. OP if this is not what you meant, please [edit] yourself.


One wire is pigtailed to one black wire in the wall with a wire nut. The other wire is pigtailed to three black wires in the wall with a wire nut. No neutral wire is connected to the switch.
....
Should I wire the new switch the same way the old one was?

Absolutely.
When all that is happening is simple replacement of a device, always put things back the way they were before.

Don't take anything more apart than you have to.
Take pictures of what is there now before disassembling anything.
Label every wire you have to disconnect, so you know which wire is which when multiple wires look the same or have the same color jacket.
Put everything back as it was before disassembly, except attach to the new device.

In your case, put all the wires that were under the same wire nut before back under the same wire nut again. If one of those wires was for the old switch, put the new switch's wire in its place. (Web-search for the proper way to connect wires with a wire nut: the right way works well, the wrong way starts fires.)
If the switch has only two power screw terminals or wires (as seen in your pictured switch), the switch is reversible and you can put either screw/wire with either connection to the house wiring, due to the nature of AC electricity.

Most basic single pole switches only open and close a circuit through a single wire. There is no need for a neutral (white wire) to be attached.
It is also common for the hot lead into the switch to be bundled (pigtailed) with other wires that need to be hot to service other devices. This is the "line"
It is normal for a second wire attached to the switch to be alone. This is the wire that will give power to the device or light. It is referred to as the "switched hot". This is the "load'
For your application, pigtail the 3 loose wires together as they were with the old switch. If needed add another wire to the new switch (Pigtail 4 together) This is the Line or the hot into the switch.
The single wire on the old switch will be the wire that services the lights. The "load or switched hot".
Do all this with the breaker off to prevent a shock
If you intend to do any more electrical work in your home, it may be worth your while to check out a few books on basic home wiring.
